# Android store array in preferences

Tags: android, preferences, android-preferences

I know only primitives can be stored in the android preferences, but do arrays count? Can I store an array of, say, Strings or booleans in an android preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you turn the array into a string.

Comment: then how to retrieve integer array again while loading array from preference for android 2.1.

Comment: turn the string into an array... (one easy way of doing this could be using JSON formatter/parser)

Answer (score 2):

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    for(int n =0;n<LevelMenu.buttonState.length;n++){ 
        LevelMenu.buttonState[n]= (byte) settings.getInt("levelsave"+n,0);
    }
```

**Above will get and populate the array and below will depopulate and save.**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   for(int n =0;n<LevelMenu.buttonState.length;n++){
        editor.putInt("levelsave"+n,LevelMenu.buttonState[n]);
   }
editor.commit();
```