# How to store one string and arrayvalue in sharedpreference?

Tags: android

I have array values of up[]={0,0,0,0,0} and view="adult" thesetwo value i want to store and retrieve in from sharedpreference how to do that...

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249996/android-store-array-in-preferences

Comment: Can you give us a little information on what exactly it is your storing here? SharedPreferences might not actually be the best thing to use, or perhaps using SharedPreferences differently might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list of preferences for you app called MY_PREFS, I'd do this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("arrayLength",up.size());
      for(int i=0; i<up.size(); i++){
         editor.putInt("up"+String.valueOf(i), up[i]);
      }
      editor.putString("view", "adult");
```

To retrieve them do:

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
   int arraySize = settings.getInt("arrayLength");
   int up[] = new int[arraySize];
   for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
      up[i] = settings.getInt("up"+String.valueOf(i));
   }
   String view = settings.getString("view");
```

Comment: in method  public void SetCaseInfo(String type,String up[]) do i have to pass like this or public void SetCaseInfo(String type,new ArrayList())

Comment: @user828948 Unless you are wanting an ArrayList just pass in your array like the top one you have posted.

Comment: i have to pass array or arraylist to store data

Comment: `public void SetCaseInfo(String type,String up[])` should work fine.

Comment: but the pbm is when i call setCaseInfo(type,teeth[i]) so this line i have to for loop.so this method will be called 32 times

Comment: public void SetCaseInfo(String PatientType,ArrayList arr){
   // All objects are from android.context.Context
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   
       editor.putInt("arrayLength",arr.size());
       for(int i=0; i<=arr.size(); i++){
          editor.putInt("Teethsselected"+String.valueOf(i), (Integer) arr.get(i));
       }
       editor.putString("view", PatientType);

 }

Comment: public void getCaseInfo() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
       int arraySize = settings.getInt("arrayLength");
       int up[] = new int[arraySize];
       for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
          up[i] = settings.getInt("Teethsselected"+String.valueOf(i));
       }
       String type = settings.getString("view");

 }

Answer (score 1):

you can do by simple way, like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

     String values="";

      for(int i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++){
         values+=","+Integer.toString(yourArray[i]);
      }

      editer.putString("array",values);
      editor.putString("view", "adult");
```

To get those values,

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", 0);

 String[] strArray=settings.getString("array").split(",");
int[] yourArray=new int[strArray.length];

for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
   yourArray[i]=Integer.toParseInt(strArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: while storing in method i have to pass one string and arraylist object right

Comment: in loop u r taking yourarray.size,nextline yourArray[i],yourarray is array or arraylist

Comment: but the pbm is when i call setCaseInfo(type,teeth[i]) so this line i have to call in for loop.so this method will be called 32 times

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I have seen you can't directly store an array in shared preferences. You can however use a for loop to save an int with an increasing name and have it call it back the same way when you need it and store it into another array.

```
for(int i=0; i<numInYourArray; i++){
editor.putInt("up"+i, up[i]);
}
```

If you aren't sure on how to use Shared Preferences in general look [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/)

Comment: is it like this   public void SetCaseInfo(String type,String up[]){
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putString(TYPE,type);  
               for(int i=0; i<up.length; i++){
               editor.putInt("up"+i, up[i]);
                    }
}