# Persistent data to save name and website from input user

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, persistent

I have two edit text for the name and the url.
After pressing "save" button I want to save this informations.

So I decided to use SharedPreferences to store it and it's ok.

`SharedPreferences addActivityPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`
`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = addActivityPrefs.edit();`
`editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString()).commit();`
`editor.putString("url", url.getText().toString()).commit();`

But my problem is when I want to store others values it overwrites my previous values
and I want to keep all of them.

this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
     <string name="url">http://Google.co.uk</string>
     <string name="name">BBC world news feed</string>
</map>
```

And my goal is to save many pairs of name-url like 
    
        http://www.google.co.uk
        GOOGLE

```
<map>
    <string name="url">http://www.yahoo.co.uk</string>
    <string name="name">YAhoo</string>
</map>
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: Why don't you use sqlite table for this?

Comment: Because I have some requirements to follow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the array as a string and save that, or you can just create a new key for each item, so have

1. location1
2. location2
3. location3

To do the second approach you can look at this question:

[Android store array in preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249996/android-store-array-in-preferences)

I would also have a key with the number of saved items, so you can load that key, increment, save, then use the new counter as the name of the new key, so `location + cntr`

Answer (score 0):

You can either create json objects with url and name and put them into a jsonArray which you can commit as string OR create your object to store the name and url, put it in a list and then just serialize/deserialize the list and put it in prefs.

PS: call commit only once after you have put both/all the values, prefferably not from the UI thread, or call just once apply().